# Azure read only sql

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have a project in azure subscription which is composed as follow:

- SQL Server
- Sql Database
- App Service API
- App Service service

What am I doing now, is assigning a managed identity to both app services and creating a connection string to the Sql Database. At the moment I am giving full permission (read and write) to both app services (API and Service) but ideally I would like to give full permission to `App service API` and give `read-only` access to `app service service`

Can please anyone guide me on the right path on how to set those permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the RBAC access to app service managed identities in the database server.

For your both application assign RBAC level of permission as per your need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage